# How to iterate Numpy array and perform calculation only if element matches a criteria?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to iterate a numpy array and process only elements match with specific criteria. In the code below, I want to perform calculation only if element is greater than 1.

```
a = np.array([[1,3,5],
              [2,4,3],
              [1,2,0]])

for i in range(0, a.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0, a.shape[1]):
        if a[i,j] > 1:
            a[i,j] = (a[i,j] - 3) * 5
```

Is it possible to use single-line code instead of the double loop above? and perhaps make it faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method #1: use a boolean array to index:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,3,5], [2,4,3], [1,2,0]])
>>> a[a > 1]  = (a[a > 1] - 3) * 5
>>> a
array([[ 1,  0, 10],
       [-5,  5,  0],
       [ 1, -5,  0]])
```

This computes `a > 1` twice, although you could assign it to a variable instead.  (In practice it's very unlikely to be a bottleneck, of course, although if `a` is large enough memory can be an issue.)

Method #2: use `np.where`:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,3,5], [2,4,3], [1,2,0]])
>>> np.where(a > 1, (a-3)*5, a)
array([[ 1,  0, 10],
       [-5,  5,  0],
       [ 1, -5,  0]])
```

This only computes `a > 1` once, but OTOH computes `(ax-3)*5` for every element `ax` in `a`, instead of only doing it for those elements that really need it.

Comment: do you have a reference for how operators within brackets work

Comment: @user1276363: I think it's called [advanced indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) but for some reason I can't connect to the numpy tutorial I was going to link to.

Comment: if you're concerned about memory, it looks like np.where returns a new array, whereas method#1 evaluates in place

Answer (score 0):

```
for index, x in np.ndenumerate(a):
    if x > 1:
        a[index] = (a[index] - 3) * 5
```